# 3D image registration from depth camera at different position

Tags: python, image-processing, 3d, computer-vision, image-registration

I have four depth cameras on a device and their relative positions are fixed. The cameras can perform simultaneous scans on an object from four different angles.

**I'd like to register four images together as one complete 3D scan.** Currently I'm **manually** registering the four scans together based on the overlapped area between the scans. Are there any methods to do the registration **automatically**? For example, an algorithm that can **detect and extract the overlap area**, then align the scans? And I might prefer a non-learning method as I don't have a GPU currently. I tried reading a few papers, but I'm not sure which one would be the best fit for me. Do you have any recommendations?

Supplementary information about the four scans:

1. The overlap area between scans is not big, taking about 5-10% area of a single scan.
2. Since the cameras are fixed, the overlapped area of the object can be determined.
3. Special markers/stickers can be attached to the overlap surface of the object(like a colored sticker or a QR code?) if it will help with the detection.

Many thanks!